# VBA code to Loop through Power Pivot Slicers and safe each item in a folder

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, powerpivot

Below code works perfectly in creating PDFs from an Excel table PivotTable and slicer however falls short when connected to a PowerPivot PivotTable with a slicer. I attempted with the modified query below but keep errorring when it get to this portion of the code:

```
If sI.Name = slDummy.Name Then slDummy.Selected = True Else: slDummy.Selected = False   
If sC.SlicerCacheLevels(1).Count = 1 Then
```

---

```
Sub PDF()

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = FALSE
        .DisplayStatusBar = FALSE
        .EnableEvents = FALSE
        .DisplayAlerts = FALSE
    End With
    
    Dim slItem      As SlicerItem
    Dim slDummy     As SlicerItem
    Dim slBox       As SlicerCache
    Dim FilePath    As String
    FilePath = "\\cdcsrvr1\Depts\C&I_Sales_Mgmt_Admin\POS_Reports\A_SALES_CREDIT\Agency Reports\"
    
    Set slBox = Workbooks("POT_POS Sales Credit MASTER.xlsm").SlicerCaches("Slicer_RollUp_Agent")
    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet
    
    MsgBox ("Letsa Go!")
    
    For Each slItem In slBox.SlicerItems
        
        slBox.ClearManualFilter
        
        For Each slDummy In slBox.SlicerItems
            
            If slItem.Name = slDummy.Name Then slDummy.Selected = TRUE Else: slDummy.Selected = FALSE
            
            If slBox.VisibleSlicerItems.Count = 1 Then
                
                Application.CalculateFull
                On Error Resume Next
                ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                                                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                                                Filename:=FilePath & Sheets("Dashboard").Range("B4") & " " & Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C10") & " - " & "R" & Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C5") & " - POT_POS SALES CREDIT - " & Sheets("Dashboard").Range("C6") & ".pdf", _
                                                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                                                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                                                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                                                OpenAfterPublish:=False
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
            
        Next slDummy
        
    Next slItem
    
    ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_RollUp_Agent").ClearManualFilter
    
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = TRUE
        .DisplayStatusBar = TRUE
        .EnableEvents = TRUE
        .DisplayAlerts = TRUE
    End With

End Sub
```